# Question about meaning of "as often as not" in this context

Tags: word-meaning

> Outside, the emergency rescue team of the Civil Defence Force (CDF) scoured through the rubble. With little training and limited equipment from Britain, America and elsewhere, **theirs** is a task as grim as it is dangerous. When there is an attack on residential areas, they race in to search for survivors and - **as often as not** - to recover bodies. In the last year, eight crew members have been killed as they brave bombs and bullets to rescue others.

What does "as often as not" mean here?

I also would appreciate your help, determining what the word "theirs" refers to.

Answer (score 2):

According to [Collins Dictionary](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-often-as-not), *as often as not* means “quite frequently”.

*Theirs* is a pronoun, the possessive form of *they* and in your context means “their task”.

You may say **the task is theirs** or as it is written on text **theirs is a task**.

Answer (score 2):

*As often as not*, if taken literally, means "at least half of the time":  in circumstances where something **could** happen, it **does** happen as often as it does **not** happen.

As an idiom, it is generally used to refer to something that happens frequently or regularly, even if it does not actually happen half or more of the time.

The initial subject of the paragraph is "The Emergency Rescue Team"; **theirs** refers directly back to this team (there is no other subject of a primary phrase between "emergency rescue team" and "theirs").

Comment: Taken literally, it could be argued *as often as not* means "exactly half of the time".